# NGRX handling errors for getting / creating / deleting

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a reducer which currently stores state for a `product`. I have the current state structure:

```
{
    draft: {},
    loading: false,
    error: false
}
```

My question here is how do I support handling errors when the user creates / deletes a product? I don't want to use the same `loading` / `error` property for getting / creating / deleting - they may need to happen simultaneously. Would I be best creating separate reducers such as `createProductReducer` / `deleteProductReducer` / `getProductReducer`, or maybe moving errors / loading into their own `errorReducer` / 'loadingReducer`?

Answer (score 1):

As a basic rule of thumb: The reduce does not contain any logic and contains (in most cases) semantically related data.

So in short: I would not advice you to split up your `productReducer` into multiple reducers.

Secondly I would suggest you to rethink the data-flow and if you *really* need to have one-time-events (errors in your case) being part of the application-state. In most cases this is not necessary.

Here is how I usually handle this:

**Errors**:
Any *external* operation(REST, db-calls ect...) is done by having an effect that calls a service-method. If an error occurs - the effect returns an action(e.g. `ERROR_ACTION`), that is only handled by some root-component to display errors (through `actions$.ofType(ERROR_ACTION)...`) - no reducer or effect listen for this action (unless there is some logging-service involved).

**Loading**: There is a reducer (`uiReducer`) that has a loading-counter (loading-event starts: +1; loading-event finishes/errors: -1) and a root-component (loading-indicator) is visible whenever the count is > 0.